# How to develop a 3D application with multi touch support?

Tags: windows-7, 3d, multi-touch

Is it possible to develop an 3D application in .Net (XNA or WPF) that would take advantage of Windows 7's multi touch support.

Is it possible to do so ?

Where is the best place to start ?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://10gui.com/? A brilliant concept...

Comment: Also check out this opensource touchlib in action here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQpr3W-YmcQ

Comment: Wow these videos are great. But is there any example/framework for using multi touch in 3D applications ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Start with [gestures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336016.aspx#id0400006)
Then dive into the [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371581(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

First: The nature of what you display is independent of whether your application supports multitouch or not.

Second: I don't believe there's a great value in having 3D interfaces whether using multitouch or not: the thing you touch is probably plain (a monitor or something the like). Better go with 2.5D (use shadows to give the whole thing a pseudo 3D look, stay away from 3D cubes).

Third: Have a well concept of user experience. What will be touchable, how will the application react (animations, etc.). Have a great look (graphics) designed and be prepared to have them changed while implementing a multitouch application. Technically, make yourself familiar with gestures, APIs and whatever it takes (the hardware is a factor as well),

The second point can (and probably should) be seen as a personal taste...